# how get my git repostory back after change system?

Tags: git

Recently, I changed my system to Linux, so my git repository on windows was lost.

But I want use it again and edit/add some files to it.

So, what should I do?

Do I need to get a new ssh keys configured?

I have looked up this site:
http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.html 
but didn't find an answer.

PS. I don't know if this question is duplicated, cause I searched but didn't find any similar results.

If there is, please just give me a reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you clone it to your Windows box from upstream source, say GitHub?  If so (as it seems because you mention ssh keys), you just need to clone again to Linux box.  And you should be good just generating new ssh keys and configuring them as trusted in upstream.

Comment: I use the command git clone git@xxxxx, and i get the message:Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: You either need to **a)** copy your ssh key from the Windows box to the Linux box or **b)** generate new key on Linux box and configure that key as authorized key at the upstream (that xxxxx).

Comment: Did you get it going?

Comment: Yes.it's going well. These days,my notebook can't connect to internet, i use my roommates's computer now